# Light switch replication

Tags: wiring, lighting, switch, smart-switch

I appear to have a not so common request.

I have two light switches which are located 1m (3ft) apart and control two ceiling lights located 2m (6ft) apart.

There must have been some idea behind it, but what I want is a single switch operating both.

I checked wiring and it seems there is no extra/common wire available in switch boxes or fixture boxes which can be used to pair these.

Looks like I have to either break wall or ceiling to add a wire or use some wireless solution; I am more inclined to second solution, though I don't want/have smart home things.

So far I found multiple wireless remote switches similar to this ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B015E7DTW4)), but they all have a finished control side (either wall-mountable switch or remote control with battery), while I need a box-with-wires control side, no batteries.

Maybe I am missing some obvious solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you on this planet? Are you averse to surface raceway/trunking as well?

Comment: How does power get from the first switch to the second switch, or between lamps? Can you shoot photos of the wiring that is behind the lamps and switches in all boxes?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, unfortunately I don't have full visibility into wiring, but I found no relation between two.  They are connected to different breakers, so I assume no connections between these circuits up here.  I'll add schematics of what is available in boxes.

Comment: there's probably a stud half-way between the two switch boxes,

Comment: @Jasen, yes.  So no easy way to push a wire.